# Free-of-cost VM (Virtual Machine) for testing (specific parameters)

Tags: windows, gratis, virtual-machine, windows-xp

A colleague wants to test some software within a VM (Virtual Machine) environment.  He wants to test it on a computer that is not hooked up to the internet.  It runs Win XP SP3.  Windows was pre-installed on that system by the system manufacturer, and he cannot find the original OS restore disks that the manufacturer provided.

Can anyone recommend free-of-cost VM software that works on Win XP SP3 that will accommodate the above parameters?

There is already a Q/A about general VM recommendations, please ensure that responses to this question meet the specific requirements outlined above.  Thanks!

Comment: When you say "It runs Win XP SP3", are you referring to the *host* system, or the *guest* system? And which system has the OS pre-installed? It's unclear why you can't simply download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and set it up with no networking, unless there's something about your question that I'm not understanding.

Comment: @GregHewgill The host system and the guest system are the same system.  Therefore, both will be Win XP SP3.

Comment: I think you may be confused about something, but I'm not sure what. When talking about virtual machines, the "host" and "guest" systems are *necessarily* different systems, they cannot be the same system. It's still unclear what you are looking for here.

Comment: @GregHewgill Lol. I might be confused or using the wrong terminology. He wants to test some software without affecting anything else on the machine. The software includes some drivers, so I don't think a simple sandbox will work.

Comment: VirtualBox, for example, is not a "simple sandbox". It's an entire virtual machine that has its own OS installation, own kernel, own drivers, own applications, and everything. Try it out, you might find it suits your needs. The guest installation does not affect anything on the host system.

Comment: @GregHewgill I will give it a try. Does it require the OS installation media or can it get everything it needs from the system on which it is installed?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: A virtual machine is like a totally separate computer. It cannot "copy" an existing installation from a host machine (unless maybe you use cloning software). If the OS you want to install requires installation media, you will need that media.

Comment: @GregHewgill He needs a solution that uses what he already has.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: You can use your choice of [disk cloning software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_cloning_software) to clone an existing machine into a VM.

Comment: @GregHewgill Thanks. I will tell him. Will there be any copy protection issues in doing that?  My understanding is that it is within the scope of the Windows license to use a copy within a VM as long as the host system is not used at the same time.  He will be compliant since he will be using one or the other, but never both.  But are there technologies in place that will prevent him from being able to do this successfully?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: I am not qualified to answer Windows licensing questions, sorry. As for technical measures, you'll probably just have to try it and see if it works. Some cloning software may work better than others, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

Any virtual machine software (free or otherwise) such as VirtualBox will work.

Ideally, obtain a copy of the Windows install media and reinstall Windows cleanly to the virtual machine as the hardware will appear different to the current installation of Windows. Copies of the install media are usually available from your computer manufacturer or directly from Microsoft for a nominal fee. You could also borrow installation media from a trusted source such as a friend or colleague. You may also be able to purchase install media via eBay or similar although this is a less trusted source.

You can retrieve your current product key using a free utility such as one found at: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/tp/topkeyfinder.htm

During a new installation, Windows will want to connect to the Internet to validate the product key and temporarily enabling an Internet connection during the install will mean that you won't have to suffer subsequent reminders.

Microsoft may detect that Windows is being installed to different hardware necessitating a phone call to Microsoft Support. Assuming the wait in the queue isn't too long, this is usually a fairly painless experience once you explain what you want to do and they flick the appropriate switch.